# How do I cancel an Outlook event for an AD user that no longer exists?

Tags: exchange, outlook

There is a recurring event which is scheduled in Outlook by a user who is no longer employed with our company (and the AD user doesn't exist, hasn't for several months but it was just now brought up). How can I go about taking control of the event and sending out a cancellation to everybody that has the event on their calendar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to restore the user and the meeting event to cancel it.  Otherwise, each user has to delete the entry from their calendar, or you can remove it from each user's calendar if you are the Exchange Administrator.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279428

Comment: I could delete it from the calendar for people inside our organization, but for those outside of it that won't work. 

Guess I'll just have to email the users and tell them to delete the event on their own.

Thanks for the assist.